# Continuity of a portfolio with two options with respect to the strikes

Tags: options

Consider the covariance, evaluated at time $t$, between two call options written on two different but not independent underlyings $S_1$ and $S_2$ defined on the same (filtered) measure space $\left(\Omega,\mathbb{F},P,\mathbb{\bar{F}}\right)$:
\begin{equation}
E_t\left(\left(\left(S_{1,T}-k_1\right)^{+}-E_t\left(\left(S_{1,T}-k_1\right)^{+}|\mathbb{F}_t\right)\right)\left(\left(S_{2,T}-k_2\right)^{+}-E_t\left(\left(S_{2,T}-k_2\right)^{+}|\mathbb{F}_t\right)\right)|\mathbb{F}_t\right)
\end{equation}
Is the correlation continuous with respect to $k_1$ and $k_2$?
Consider each component of the covariance and let $\tilde{\Omega}$ be the space of events that make the payoff of both call options positive:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
E_t\left(\left(S_{1,T}-k_1\right)^{+}\left(S_{2,T}-k_2\right)^{+}|\mathbb{F}_t\right)&=E_{t,\tilde{\Omega}}\left(\left(S_{1,T}-k_1\right)\left(S_{2,T}-k_2\right)|\mathbb{F}_t\right)=\\
&= E_{t,\tilde{\Omega}}\left(S_{1,T}S_{2,T}-k_1S_{2,T}-S_{1,T}k_2+k_1k_2|\mathbb{F}_t\right)=\\
&=E_{t,\tilde{\Omega}}\left(S_{1,T}S_{2,T}|\mathbb{F}_t\right)-E_{t,\tilde{\Omega}}\left(S_{2,T}|\mathbb{F}_t\right)k_1+\\
&-E_{t,\tilde{\Omega}}\left(S_{1,T}\right)k_2+k_1k_2P\left(\tilde{\Omega}\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
E_t\left(\left(S_{1,T}-k_1\right)^{+}|\mathbb{F}\right)E_t\left(\left(S_{2,T}-k_2\right)^{+}|\mathbb{F}\right)&=E_{t,\tilde{\Omega}}\left(\left(S_{1,T}-k_1\right)|\mathbb{F}\right)E_{t,\tilde{\Omega}}\left(\left(S_{2,T}-k_2\right)|\mathbb{F}\right)\\
&=E_{t,\tilde{\Omega}}\left(\left(S_{1,T}\right)|\mathbb{F}\right)E_{t,\tilde{\Omega}}\left(\left(S_{2,T}\right)|\mathbb{F}\right)-E_{t,\tilde{\Omega}}\left(\left(S_{1,T}\right)|\mathbb{F}\right)k_2-E_{t,\tilde{\Omega}}\left(\left(S_{2,T}\right)|\mathbb{F}\right)k_1+k_1k_2P\left(\tilde{\Omega}\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Therefore I'd conclude that the correlation is continuous in both $k_1$ and $k_2$. Is this correct?